# thread cancelation in pthread in linux environment

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, cancellation

I executed the following sample code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void * thread_func(void *ignored_argument) {
    int s;

    s = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
    sleep(5);
    s = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);

         **while (1);**
         sleep(1000);

    printf("thread_func(): not canceled!\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thr;
    void *res;
    int s;

    s = pthread_create(&thr, NULL, &thread_func, NULL);

    sleep(9);
    printf("main(): sending cancellation request\n");
    s = pthread_cancel(thr);


    s = pthread_join(thr, &res);
    if (res == PTHREAD_CANCELED)
        printf("main(): thread was canceled\n");
    else
        printf("main(): thread wasn't canceled (shouldn't happen!)\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

when I comment bolded while (1) line (about line 14), thread was cancelled, but when I uncomment this line thread cancellation does not work.

As I understand pthread_cancel, canlcel running and sleeped thread.  is it right? if yes please help me about the mentioned code.

linux man page and also search in google

Comment: Does calling `pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);` from within the thread-callback make any difference?

Comment: You may want to tag this with the programming language that you target. Also, replace "linux" with "pthreads" while you're at it. POSIX threads are not Linux-specific!

Comment: Note that `while (1);` is undefined behaviour (UB) in C++ (but not in C) so the language matters a lot. Programs containing UB are ill-formed and compilers are free to generate wrong code with weird unexpected behaviours (spoil : optimizers actually often do that).

Comment: From the pthread manual: the *deferred* cancellation type is *"the default for new threads"* and *"deferred cancelability means that cancelation will be delayed until the thread next calls a function that is a cancelation point"* . The list of cancellation point is provided in the manual. Few system functions are *required* to be cancellation points (like `sleep`), many *can* be, and `while(1);` is apparently not.

Comment: regarding to Jeremy Friesner post, It was solved.

Comment: The #1 rule of `pthread_cancel()` is **never call `pthread_cancel()`**.  Thread cancellation is extremely hard to work with.  It is almost never the best approach to any problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the `pthread(7)` manual:

> **Cancelation points**
>
> POSIX.1 specifies that certain functions must, and certain other
> functions may, be cancelation points.  If a thread is cancelable,
> its cancelability type is deferred, and a cancelation request is
> pending for the thread, then the thread is canceled when it calls
> a function that is a cancelation point.
> The following functions are required to be cancelation points by
> POSIX.1-2001 and/or POSIX.1-2008:
>
> - accept()
> - ...
> - sleep()

So `while(1);` is not a cancellation point.

To cancel a thread not a a cancellation point, you have to call `pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);`:

> The `pthread_setcanceltype()` sets the cancelability type of the
> calling thread to the value given in type. The type argument must
> have one of the following values:
>
> **PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED**
>
> A cancelation request is deferred until the thread next
> calls a function that is a cancelation point (see
> pthreads(7)).  This is the default cancelability type in
> all new threads, including the initial thread.
>
> Even with deferred cancelation, a cancelation point in an
> asynchronous signal handler may still be acted upon and
> the effect is as if it was an asynchronous cancelation.
>
> **PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS**
>
> The thread can be canceled at any time.  (Typically, it
> will be canceled immediately upon receiving a cancelation
> request, but the system doesn't guarantee this.)